# @capacitor-community/electron gives Unhandled Promise Rejection on built package

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, electron-builder, ionic5

When I pack my Ionic project with `@capacitor-community/electron` packager (using electron-builder), I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:/Users/.../example/electron/dist/win-unpacked/resources/app-update.yml'
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

```sh
# create generic ionic example
ionic start example tabs --type angular
cd example
npm i @capacitor-community/electron --save-dev
# required to add electron
ionic build
npx cap add @capacitor-community/electron
cd electron
# runs npm run build && electron-builder build --dir -c ./builder-effective-config.yaml
npm run electron:pack
```

Here is the package.json of main `./example` project:

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor-community/electron": "^4.0.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.2.4",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.3",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.2.4",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Here is `package.json` of `./example/electron` project:

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An Amazing Capacitor App",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": ""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "build/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && electron-rebuild",
    "electron:start-live": "node ./live-runner.js",
    "electron:start": "npm run build && electron --inspect=5858 ./",
    "electron:pack": "npm run build && electron-builder build --dir -c ./electron-builder.config.json",
    "electron:make": "npm run build && electron-builder build -c ./electron-builder.config.json -p always"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-community/electron": "^4.0.1",
    "chokidar": "~3.5.2",
    "electron-is-dev": "~2.0.0",
    "electron-serve": "~1.1.0",
    "electron-unhandled": "~3.0.2",
    "electron-updater": "~4.3.9",
    "electron-window-state": "~5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "~13.1.9",
    "electron-builder": "~22.11.7",
    "electron-rebuild": "~2.3.5",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "capacitor",
    "electron"
  ]
}
```

And here is `electron-builder.config.json` file:

```json
{
  "appId": "com.yourdoamnin.yourapp",
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "resources"
  },
  "files": [
    "assets/**/*",
    "build/**/*",
    "capacitor.config.*",
    "app/**/*"
  ],
  "publish": {
    "provider": "github"
  },
  "nsis": {
    "allowElevation": true,
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "win": {
    "target": "nsis",
    "icon": "assets/appIcon.ico"
  },
  "mac": {
    "category": "your.app.category.type",
    "target": "dmg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently problem lies in default publish method. You need to change your `electron-builder.config.json` file to the following form (without the comment):

```json
{
  "appId": "com.yourdoamnin.yourapp",
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "resources"
  },
  "files": [
    "assets/**/*",
    "build/**/*",
    "capacitor.config.*",
    "app/**/*"
  ],
  "publish": {
    "provider": "github",
    "publishAutoUpdate": false // This is the line you need to add!
  },
  "extends":null,
  "nsis": {},
  "win": {
    "target": "nsis",
    "icon": "assets/appIcon.ico"
  }
}
```